# Python selenium Error: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I am getting this error while trying to fill up form.

Error:

> "no such element: Unable to locate element:
>
> {"method":"id","selector":"formId:codEmpresa"}".

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www3.honda.com.br/newihs")

chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:codEmpresa").send_keys("Text1")
chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:codUsuario").send_keys("Text2")
chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:senha").send_keys("Text2")
chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:j_id68").click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the login form containing your ids is in an iframe. Try https://www3.honda.com.br/newihs/pages/loginExterno.iface

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www3.honda.com.br/newihs/pages/loginExterno.iface")

chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:codEmpresa").send_keys("Text1")
chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:codUsuario").send_keys("Text2")
chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:senha").send_keys("Text2")
chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:j_id68").click
```